# 3.5" internal HDD unplugged itself while zero-writing to bad sectors

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Samsung HD642JJ 640gB HDD connected through a SATA3 6.0G/s channel, it has sever bad sectors on it, so I was going to low level format it with HDD Low Level Format Tool 4.40.

What happened was, when writing to the bad blocks, the HDD went unplugged. So I pulled it out, tried with a USB 3.0 HDD dock, then there was the same symptom.

What am I supposed to do? (not getting a new one)

Comment: Sounds like the drive is actually dead.

Comment: Good news is? There's no unwanted data loss. Bad news is that you might have gotten a more *permanent* failure mode - I'd try inspecting the controller board visually for chips that seem fried. It might also potentially be a firmware issue, but that sort of thing is usually well documented and common to the same family/model of drive. I suspect the only alternative to not replacing the drive is to not have a drive at all.